# Tensorflow dataset from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have two numpy Arrays (X, Y) which I want to convert to a tensorflow dataset. [According to the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy#load_numpy_arrays_with_tfdatadataset) it should be possible to run

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, Y))
model.fit(train_dataset)
```

When doing this however I get the error:
`ValueError: Shapes (15, 1) and (768, 15) are incompatible`

This would make sense if the shapes of the numpy Arrays would be incompatible to the expected inputs/outputs.
But if I run it with the numpy arrays by using `model.fit(X,Y)` it runs without any problems, so the shapes seem to be okay.

In a next step I checked the output sizes:

```
>>> train_dataset.batch(4)
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 768), (None, 15)), types: (tf.int64, tf.uint8)>
```

The input layer for the neural network expect (None, None) and the output (None, 15). So this also seems to match.

My dataset is rather large, so it's difficult to share that, but here is a minimal reproducible example which shows the problem. It's the same error, and the fit with just the numpy arrays works.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(10,size=(10,20,1))
b = np.random.rand(10,15)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a,b))

inp = Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int32")
embedding = Embedding(12, 300, trainable=False, mask_zero=True)(inp)
gru = Bidirectional(GRU(128, recurrent_dropout=0.5))(embedding)
out = Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)(gru)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)
out = Dense(15, activation='sigmoid')(out)
m = Model(inputs=inp, outputs = out)
m.compile("adam", 'categorical_crossentropy')

m.fit(a,b)
m.fit(train_dataset)
```

Can someone point me into the right direction on how to solve this?

Tensorflow version is 2.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you batch your dataset:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a,b)).batch(4)
```