# Conversion of numpy array inside a pandas dataset to a TensorFlow dataset using data api

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am running TensorFlow 2.12.0  and python 3.11 for a ML classification project where i have a dataset as follows: -
[image]

I have use pandas for data preprocessing and hthis resulted in this: The f_combined column is a numpy array of **constant size 12** for each row. and asthama_status is a string

when i try to convert the dataset to a TFDS as follows: -

```
ds_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    df['asthma_status'],
    df['f_combined']
))
```

I get the error as follows: -
[image]

looking at other questions I have tried adding batch but the same error message is diplayed: -

```
ds_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    df['asthma_status'],
    df['f_combined']
)).batch(8)
```

I have also tried converting it to a `tf.constant` before conversion to tfds but it still doesn't work:-
`df['f_combined'] = df['f_combined'].progress_apply(lambda x: tf.constant(x))`
[image]

I have also looked at [Tensorflow dataset from numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716925/tensorflow-dataset-from-numpy-array) and the partial code given works:-

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(10,size=(10,20,1))
b = np.random.rand(10,15)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a,b))
```

My questions are:

1. What am i doing wrong with my code?
2. How do i actually achieve this?
3. if not possible, what is a alternative way to do this by further prepossessing in pandas?

Comment: Check `df.to_numpy()`.  My guess is that will be an object dtype array, with the elements being lists or arrays (or maybe strings).  I think you'll need to clean that up, and make the tensor from the result.

Comment: @hpaulj i tried it but it gives me the same error. can you clarify how to clean it up?

Comment: tell us about the array..  shape? dtype?

Comment: the array has a shape (775426, 2) and if i take shape of arr[0][1], it is (12,). type is object

Comment: So `arr` contains objects, probably arrays (maybe lists).  `np.stack(arr[:,1])` might work to make a (775426,12) numeric dtype array.  Similarly for the other column.

Comment: That just puts all the rows as a single row when converting to TFDS